# Find " - " in TXT file and switch before with after and vice versa

Tags: sorting, batch-file, find

I have a text file with a list of books sorted by author named `author.txt`. I want to make a new list sorted by title and author named `title.txt` from the `author.txt` list file.

The `author.txt` is constant with this layout: "author name" "space" "hyphen" "space" "title".

Here is an excerpt:

```
Aaron James - Assholes--A Theory
Adam Grant - Originals_ How Non-Conformists Move the World
Adam Lashinsky - Inside Apple
Adam Penenberg - Viral Loop (Facebook to Twitter)
Adam Rothstein - The End of Money
Agatha Christie - And Then There Were None
Al Murray - Let's Re-Great Britain
Alan Dean Foster - The Dig
Alan Furst - Night Soldiers
Alan Glynn - Limitless
Alan Greenspan - The Map and the Territory
Alan Moore - V for vendetta
Alastair Reynolds - Century Rain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript and store it in same directory as the batch file below containing also `author.txt`.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF
if not exist "author.txt" goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^(.+) - (.+)$" "$2 - $1" /F "author.txt" | %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /O "title.txt"
```

The command **CALL** would not be necessary here because of redirection operator `|` which results in continuation of batch file execution on this batch file after finishing execution of **JREPL.BAT**. But in general it is necessary to use command **CALL** to run another batch file from within a batch file and continue the execution on the calling batch file after finishing execution of called batch file (not containing command `exit` without option `/B`).

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `sort /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to convert a sorted list `<author> - <title>` into a resorted list `<title> - <author>`. Here is a (currently untested!) pure batch script approach, relying on the assumption that no `<author>` part contains the separator sequence <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `-` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> on its own:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem //Define constants here:
set "_INFILE=author.txt"
set "_OUTFILE=title.txt"
set "_TMPFILE=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"
set "_SEP= - "
(set _NL=^
%= empty line =%
)

> "%_TMPFILE%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_INFILE%") do (
        set "AUTHOR=" & set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%T in ("!LINE:*%_SEP%=!") do (
            for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (^"!LINE:%_SEP%^=^%_NL%%_NL%!^") do (
                endlocal
                if not defined AUTHOR (
                    set "AUTHOR=%%A"
                    set "TITLE=%%T"
                )
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        if defined AUTHOR echo(!TITLE!%_SEP%!AUTHOR!
        endlocal
    )
)
sort "%_TMPFILE%" /O "%_OUTFILE%"
del "%_TMPFILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Great solution for a pure Windows command processor solution working also for `author.txt` containing `!"%` in titles. It is really interesting for me to see how difficult to solve a text file reformatting task is which I have done first with text editor UltraEdit with pressing Ctrl+R, entering regular expression search string `^(.+) - (.+)$` and `\2 - \1` as replace string, running the Perl regular expression __Replace all__, sorting the lines with UltraEdit's __Sort__ command, and finally saving the reformatted file after pressing F12 as `title.txt` which took me just 15 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for testing! ;-) Yes, I see; unfortunately, `cmd` lacks a nice regex tool for such easy tasks...

Answer (score 0):

For a perl implementation:

```
open (my FILE,"<","author.txt"); # Provide complete path
@authorlist = <FILE>;
s/^(.+?)\s*?-\s*?(.+)\s*+$/$2 - $1/ or warn "Unable to match regex in line: $_\n" foreach (@authorlist);
print join("\n",@authorlist);
```

Just tested equivalent code and is working fine.

Obtained output when provided excerpt as input:

> Assholes--A Theory - Aaron James
>    Originals_ How Non-Conformists Move the World - Adam Grant
>    Inside Apple - Adam Lashinsky
>    Viral Loop (Facebook to Twitter) - Adam Penenberg
>    The End of Money - Adam Rothstein
>    And Then There Were None - Agatha Christie
>    Let's Re-Great Britain - Al Murray
>    The Dig - Alan Dean Foster
>    Night Soldiers - Alan Furst
>    Limitless - Alan Glynn
>    The Map and the Territory - Alan Greenspan
>    V for vendetta - Alan Moore
>    Century Rain - Alastair Reynolds

The warn statement will be helpful to determine where the regex fails (if at all).